# Wordpress slow even use blank template

Tags: performance, debug

I am working on a wordpress based website,while I found that it is too slow for loading the page itself(without the static resources), the `TTFB` of the request for a post is almost 1.7s in case of deactivate all the plugins(exclude debug bar) and using the `twentysixteen` theme and also just include the `wp-header` and `wp-footer` for the `single.php` . See the screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Then I change the `single.php` of the theme to a blank file, and get almost the same `TTFB`:
[image]

BTW, I use [wmnp](https://www.getwnmp.org/) with PHP7.0.8 Mysql5.5.5 and Nginx1.11.2 in Windows 10 X64.

What can be the reason result in that?

Comment: don't measure this kind of performance on your local pc. do it only on a proper web server. There are too many other things that happen on your PC

Comment: Indeed, my PC is a workstation with a rather wonderful performance. I have never meet this kind of performance problem when working with JavaEE or nodejs application.